# Application got stuck on downloading

Tags: objective-c, blocking

I am working on an iPhone app, which downloads Focus list of items on each app start (6 items with images).

I'm using 1 NSMutableURLRequest for downloading 6 items textual information in a loop, then in the same method block with different for loop I'm using :

```
NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString: strUrl];
NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
```

for getting images of all 6 items. Code is working fine, if I wait till this process completes and update my list on home view. 
If I try to navigate then my app stuck till its in process of download. I called complete method on Background thread, but still it got stuck for the process completion.

How can I code for this, so user can experience all navigation without stuck and when he'll come back can get the 6 items in view ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NSURLConnections` [asynchronous request](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendAsynchronousRequest%3aqueue%3acompletionHandler%3a) to do the downloads in the background

```
+ (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*))handler`
```

That way the download won't block your code. You can also do the completion work on background thread (as long as its not working with the UI, that code ALWAYS needs to be on the main thread).